# Split package issue with Google Analytics Data API

Tags: java, maven, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, java-17

Split package issue with Google Analytics Data API

I am getting errors like below:

[

```
ERROR] error: module spring.data.commons reads package com.google.analytics.data.v1beta from both google.analytics.data and proto.google.analytics.data.v1beta
[ERROR] error: module spring.data.jpa reads package com.google.analytics.data.v1beta from both google.analytics.data and proto.google.analytics.data.v1beta
[ERROR] error: module spring.ldap.core reads package com.google.analytics.data.v1beta from both google.analytics.data and proto.google.analytics.data.v1beta
[ERROR] error: module spring.tx reads package com.google.analytics.data.v1beta from both google.analytics.data and proto.google.analytics.data.v1beta
[ERROR] error: module spring.jdbc reads package com.google.analytics.data.v1beta from both google.analytics.data and proto.google.analytics.data.v1beta
[ERROR] error: module spring.orm reads package com.google.analytics.data.v1beta from both google.analytics.data and proto.google.analytics.data.v1beta
[ERROR] error: module spring.webmvc reads package com.google.analytics.data.v1beta from both google.analytics.data and proto.google.analytics.data.v1beta
[ERROR] error: module spring.web reads package com.google.analytics.data.v1beta from both google.analytics.data and proto.google.analytics.data.v1beta
[ERROR] error: module spring.beans reads package com.google.analytics.data.v1beta from both google.analytics.data and proto.google.analytics.data.v1beta
[ERROR] error: module spring.context.support reads package com.google.analytics.data.v1beta from both google.analytics.data and proto.google.analytics.data.v1beta
[ERROR] error: module SparseBitSet reads package com.google.analytics.data.v1beta from both google.analytics.data and proto.google.analytics.data.v1beta
[ERROR] error: module commons.math3 reads package com.google.analytics.data.v1beta from both google.analytics.data and proto.google.analytics.data.v1beta
[ERROR] error: module thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4 reads package com.google.analytics.data.v1beta from both google.analytics.data and proto.google.analytics.data.v1beta
[ERROR] error: module thymeleaf.layout.dialect reads package com.google.analytics.data.v1beta from both google.analytics.data and proto.google.analytics.data.v1beta
[ERROR] error: module org.apache.commons.collections4 reads package com.google.analytics.data.v1beta from both google.analytics.data and proto.google.analytics.data.v1beta
[ERROR] error: module org.apache.poi.poi reads package com.google.analytics.data.v1beta from both google.analytics.data and proto.google.analytics.data.v1beta
[ERROR] error: module org.apache.poi.ooxml reads package com.google.analytics.data.v1beta from both google.analytics.data and proto.google.analytics.data.v1beta
[ERROR] error: module spring.context reads package com.google.analytics.data.v1beta from both google.analytics.data and proto.google.analytics.data.v1beta
```

I am using maven build tool with dependecy :
`<groupId>com.google.analytics</groupId> <artifactId>google-analytics-data</artifactId> <version>0.45.0</version>`

`Spring version: 6.0.14 Spring Security Verison: 6.0.8 Spring Boot Version: 3.1.2`

I tried the Google Analytics with Java 8 and it is working.

Comment: Looks like 2 modules with the same package in it are in your dependencies. Could you run `mvn dependency:tree` to see what is pulling in the `google.analytics.data` and `proto.google.analytics.data.v1beta` dependencies?